# JavaScript cookies to persist radio button settings

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want the radio button list values to be saved in JavaScript till the time the browser is closed (non-persistent cookies). I want to do that, instead of what happens now: when the page is reloaded my radio button list resets.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAttachmentType" runat="server" CssClass="radio" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        ToolTip="Select the type of file you want to upload.">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="101">Picture</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="102">Floor Plan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="300">Video</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="200">Document</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set expiration date/time to cookie, browser will treat it as "session" cookie, so it will not write it to persistent storage and you'll lose it after browser close. In most basic case, it's enough to

```
document.cookie = key + "=" + value;
```

If you already use some wrap function, investigate how to write cookie without expiration date.